# Как сделать адрес сайта  коротким?

Tags: домен, поддомены

Как сделать адрес сайта  коротким?  или 
Как, используя  домен с коротким  названием,  переправить  посетителя  на  другой сайт с длинным и не  запоминающимся  адресом ? Нужен HTML код !

Comment: К сожалению, никак.

Answer (score 4):

тебе поможет http://bit.ly вбиваешь свой URL нажимаешь Shorten и вот тебе короткое имя )

Answer (score 4):

Вот (неполный) список сервисов, которые позволяют сделать редирект на ваш адрес: http://longurl.org/services

Популярные сервисы:

- http://goo.gl
- http://bit.ly + http://j.mp
- http://TinyUrl.com
- http://t.co
- http://is.gd
- http://ow.ly
- http://tiny.cc

Answer (score 3):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="N;URL=адрес">
```

Comment: Плюс за чтение вопроса)

Answer (score 1):

Эффективным решением будет редирект непосредственно с сервера с кодом 301.

**Apache** *.htaccess*

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
  header('Location: http://www.example.com', true, 301);
  exit();
?>
```

Или на стороне клиента c помощью **Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location = "http://www.example.com";
</script>
```

но с использованием *canonical* для поисковой оптимизации

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com">
```

Как вариант можно использовать [сервис](http://dus.su/) сокращения ссылок.

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь http://goo.gl - там редирект без рекламы. Только следует учитывать, что там регистр ссылки важен. Но у других подобных сервисов вроде так же.